# Use "basic CAN" if "full CAN" is available?

Tags: can

From all I've read about both types my conclusion is that the only reason for using "Basic CAN" is to make message handling easier: I have to care about only one buffer.
One big drawback is that CPU load depends on CAN bus load (recently I overheard a discussion where exactly this was causing issues in a project).
So if I have "Full CAN" available, would there be any other justification for not using it?

To add some clarification:
Actually I'm not referring to any specific hardware. The project I mentioned uses a state-of-the-art microcontroller (Renesas RH850).
The Third Party CAN software package comes with a configuration tool, and in this tool it's possible to configure "Basic CAN" or "Full CAN".
"Basic CAN" means exactly what I wrote before: One Mailbox, no HW filter.

Comment: Your question presumes everyone knows the background to the question. Please edit your question and describe which system and parts you are using (datasheet link plus a description good enough to not need everyone to use the link to get broad info). The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Thanks.

Comment: Far as I understand it, "basic CAN" and "full CAN" are archaic terms of how to categorize certain historic, external CAN controllers back in the early 90s something. These controllers are long since obsolete and everyone uses built-in CAN controllers in the MCU since around year 2000. Are you maintaining some very old system or what's the reason for bringing this up?

Comment: @Lundin As I mentioned: I overheard a discussion on this and I'm just curious why one would configure a by far NOT archaic setup to implement "Basic CAN".

Comment: Probably the people involved have no clue what they are talking about? Maybe they confused it with standard and extended identifiers or something like that. Or maybe you have some very old protocol stack which supports all manner of obsolete controllers.

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you link to the pdf for the user manual of the part you are using? Specifically the one containing documentation of the CAN peripheral.